# Change in the mouse position

Tags: javascript, graphics, three.js

I am drawing a box with the mouse, where I am using raycast to get the position of the mouse in the scene. So when the mouseDown event fires, I take the starting point, and while mouseMove is happening, I take the ending point and then I draw a box between the two points.
I started in a blank page just to try the drawing, and when everything was good, I moved the drawing code to my main page which contains many components, and a container for the drawing canvas of course.
After moving my code to the main page, a problem appeared with the mouse position. the box position is shifted by the distance of the canvas container on x and y.

The following image illustrate the problem:

[image: Simplified case of the problem]

The red mark show where I pressed the mouse to start drawing the box and the blue one shows where I stopped the mouse, the shiffting here is on the Y axis because I have two rows of components in the top of the page.

This is a simplified code:

```
<body>

<div>
    <button class="btn btn-info" onclick="rotate_x()"><b>X</b></button>
    <button class="btn btn-info" onclick="rotate_y()"><b>Y</b></button>
    <button class="btn btn-info" onclick="rotate_z()"><b>Z</b></button>
    <button class="btn btn-info" onclick="reset_rotation()"><b>Reset</b></button>
    <input type="checkbox" name="selection" onchange="selection_mode_change()" checked><b>Selection mode</b>
</div>


<div>
    <button class="btn btn-info" onclick="rotate_x()"><b>X</b></button>
    <button class="btn btn-info" onclick="rotate_y()"><b>Y</b></button>
    <button class="btn btn-info" onclick="rotate_z()"><b>Z</b></button>
    <button class="btn btn-info" onclick="reset_rotation()"><b>Reset</b></button>
    <input type="checkbox" name="selection" onchange="selection_mode_change()" checked><b>Selection mode</b>
</div>
<script>

    var container;
    var camera, scene, renderer, dirLight;
    var raycaster;
    var mouse;
    var is_mouse_down = false;
    var area;
    var start, end;
    var objects = [];

    init();
    animate();

    function init() {

        container = document.createElement('div');
        document.body.appendChild(container);

        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000000);
        camera.position.set(0, 0, 1000);

        scene = new THREE.Scene();           


        // Box
        var area_geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
        area = new THREE.Mesh(area_geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            color: 0x00ff00,
            opacity: 0.2,
            visible: true
        }));
        area.position.x = 0;
        area.position.y = 0;
        area.position.z = 0;
        area.scale.x = 1;
        area.scale.y = 1;
        area.scale.z = 1;

        scene.add(area);

        // plane for the raycast intersection

        var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(100, 100, 100);
        var object = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            color: Math.random() * 0xffffff,
            opacity: 0.1,
            visible: false
        }));
        object.position.x = 0;
        object.position.y = 0;
        object.position.z = -1000;
        object.scale.x = 100;
        object.scale.y = 100;
        object.scale.z = 1;
        scene.add(object);
        objects.push(object);



        raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
        mouse = new THREE.Vector2();


        // Light
        dirLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
        dirLight.position.set(camera.position.x, camera.position.y, camera.position.z);
        scene.add(dirLight);

        renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
        renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff);
        renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        document.addEventListener('mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false);
        document.addEventListener('mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp, false);
        document.addEventListener('mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false);
        document.addEventListener('touchstart', onDocumentTouchStart, false);

        window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);

    }

    function onWindowResize() {

        camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

    }

    function onDocumentTouchStart(event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        event.clientX = event.touches[0].clientX;
        event.clientY = event.touches[0].clientY;
        onDocumentMouseDown(event);

    }

    function onDocumentMouseDown(event) {

        event.preventDefault();
        start = get_intersection_point(event);
        is_mouse_down = true;
    }

    function onDocumentMouseUp(event) {

        event.preventDefault();
        is_mouse_down = false;
    }

    function onDocumentMouseMove(event) {

        if (is_mouse_down) {

            end = intersection(event);
            update_selection_area_view(start, end);
        }
    }

    function animate() {

        requestAnimationFrame(animate);

        render();
    }

    function render() {

        camera.lookAt(scene.position);

        renderer.render(scene, camera);

    }

    function get_intersection_point(event) {
        mouse.x = ( event.clientX / renderer.domElement.clientWidth ) * 2 - 1;
        mouse.y = -( event.clientY / renderer.domElement.clientHeight ) * 2 + 1;

        raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);

        var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(objects);

        if (intersects.length > 0) {

            return intersects[0].point;

        }
        return null;
    }


    function update_selection_area_view(start, end) {

        width = Math.abs(start.x - end.x);
        height = Math.abs(start.y - end.y);

        center = new THREE.Vector3(-(start.x + end.x) / 2, -(start.y + end.y) / 2, (start.z + end.z) / 2);

        area.position.x = center.x;
        area.position.y = center.y;
        area.position.z = center.z;
        area.scale.x = width;
        area.scale.y = height;
        area.scale.z = 1;
    }

</script>

</body>
```

I don't know why this is happening, and how to solve this problem.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look closely at your picture, you will notice that the clicks are offset by a Y value (in terms of screen pixels). If you look even closer, it appears that the shift is the same as your header (the XYZ/Selection mode header). This is due to the fact that you created a div, and set it's size to the innerWidth/innerHeight. It creates a div with the specified size, but down lower. So your mouse clicks would be correct if you didn't have that header (since threejs is registering them at 40px on screen, it will translate that to 40px on the div)

HOW TO FIX:
When I had this issue, I used JQuery to get the TOP and just added that offset to my raycaster mouseclick, in your case, I think you can get renderer.domElement.top (I'm not too sure, console.log(renderer.domElement to see if there is a top location value) and subtract it to the mouse Y (Subtract since you want to shift the rectangle up)

Comment: Thank you, I knew the reason of the problem and I didn't know how to express my need.

I found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29518886/moved-coordinates-of-the-scene-when-dom-element-with-renderer-is-not-at-the-top

where you get the top of the container with: container.getBoundingClientRect().top

Thanks ^_^